# How to refresh TableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unit-testing, xcode8

I am in a bigger project that uses the Cedar framework for Unit Tests. I am writing unit tests for a view that contains a UITableView.

Initialization:

```
subject = [[ControllerWithTableView alloc] initWithParams:params];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:subject];
```

Then I set up some things and call:

```
[subject: viewWillAppear:NO];
```

In the test I can ask for cells at indexPaths etc.
The main idea behind this is that it runs without letting the UI much time to set up.

In some tests I had to add:

```
[subject.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

and *then* it worked.

But in the current test I am adding a new tableViewRow with the same method that is called during runtime. But I can't get the test to reload the UITableView to create the new row and cell and so to test it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365775/testing-the-existence-of-a-presentedviewcontroller-using-cedar) is suggested to use:

```
#define tickRunLoop (CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.01, false))
```

It works. But sometimes it crashes. Not just fails one test but crashes the process of running the unit tests. So all other tests are not run to the end. I can't push unstable code to the customer's repo so that is not an option...

I am using XCode 8.3.3 if that's relevant.

What else can I do to force a refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it was my fault. I had

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // stuff
});
```

in my code (or at least in the project. It was not my code :P).
So the test was faster than the execution of the code that should have been tested. Always be careful with async stuff!

In all cases `[subject.view layoutIfNeeded];` is enough to force a refresh now.